# Having issue modifying theme code to replace logo URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Using WordPress on the default twentysixteen theme. This is a code issue not a theme issue which is why I'm posting it on SO. I have a feeling I'm just doing something simple wrong but I've searched and figured out what code I need to change but it seems like it's not making the changes as expected.

So what I'd like to do is change the LOGO that is currently going to the website "home". I'm talking about the front end logo at the top left that i'd like to go to one of my other sites which has more relevant information.

But when I change this code:

```
        <div class="header-image">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_custom_header()->attachment_id ) ); ?>" sizes="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_header_sizes ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
            </a>
```

To:

```
        <div class="header-image">
            <a href="http://external-website-here.com">
                <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( get_custom_header()->attachment_id ) ); ?>" sizes="<?php echo esc_attr( $custom_header_sizes ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
            </a>
```

It doesn't seem to be affecting where I'm redirected when clicking on the logo image. In other words it still goes to the home_url it seems instead of the external site.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Additional Information: No caching is enabled, tried other browser/devices to make sure it's not a cache issue.

Update: Even remove the entire code from my first code box it doesn't change anything on the front end. Maybe I'm modifying the wrong file? How do I figure out what file the logo code is living in?

Comment: If you don't include http:// at the beginning of a link to an external site it will go to http://yousite.com/external-website-here.com. If that's not the issue then it's most likely a wordpress specific issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did have http:// on the actual code and have updated my question to show it. Any other suggestions are appreciated Antony thanks

Comment: Can you try in incognito window? It may be a cache.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov I have tried incognito, a different browser and even another device. Seems to still point to the home_url. Thanks for the comment if you've got any other suggestions please comment. Thank you

Comment: I have an update. Even remove the entire code it doesn't change anything on the front end. Maybe I'm modifying the wrong file? How do I figure out what file the logo code is living in?

Comment: Changing the href attr in header.php changes the url. Are you sure that you are using the twentysixteen theme? Also are you sure that you are make the changes in the same theme? Please delete the entire header.php content and let us know what do you see.

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov As expected it breaks the theme. But that attribute change does not take affect

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your site please?

Comment: Here is my test environment. http://104.236.220.40/ This is to show you the code I changed: http://prntscr.com/d8baox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong code.

You need to edit line 35 and 37 of the header.php, which I can see here: https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/header.php

This is because you don't have a logo, as far as I can tell anyway.

**Update:**

I've updated your site to work.

What I did was add function to filter the home url;

```
//functions.php (end of file)
/**
 * Changes the url returned from home_url();
 */
function change_home_link($url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id){
    return 'http://google.com';
}
```

Then add and remove the filter in the header

```
//header.php line 32
add_filter( 'home_url', 'change_home_link' );
twentysixteen_the_custom_logo();
remove_filter( 'home_url', 'change_home_link' );
```

You could also just remove the `twentysixteen_the_custom_logo()` function and replace it with what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I had setup the test environment without the logo, my apologies. I have added the image logo now and changed the lines as you suggested. The image title was successfully changed but the image logo has not despite line 92 being changed as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @d.ariel so you're line 92 looks like this?
`<a href="http://google.com" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">` ?

Comment: It's really strange that it wouldn't work. I can see you've added the custom-logo-link class so it's definitely picking up your change. It's hard to know what could be the problem without seeing it. I wouldn't mind having a quick look if you gave me WP access. email me at  stackoverflow at antz.me if you want me to.

Comment: Yup I sent you an email. Thanks Antony

Comment: Thanks a lot Antony. I had selected your answer as the correct one your answer solved it precisely.